# removeAllAnimation does not cause Completion handler finished to be NO

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, animation

If I call [self.view.layer removeAllAnimations] on a previous UIVIEW animation with completion handler, immediately start another animation on the same view with completion handler, the previous completion handler still runs even though I did a Finished check.

The problem goes away(previous animation completion handler's finish is set to NO) if I don't immediately start a new animation.

Is there any way around this?? This looks like an Apple bug.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.  I had a UIView animation block that runs another UIView Animation block.  The first block did not check for finish, but the second one did.

So when I check for the first block's finished, it did get set to NO.